# Remove leading and trailing brackets in a String

Tags: java, string, substring

In Java, I want to get rid of the leading and trailing brackets in a String.
Given input:

```
"[ hello, char[]={a,b,c} ... bye ]"
```

How can I produce the output of

```
" hello, char[]={a,b,c} ... bye "
```

only the leading `[` and trailing `]` is removed... How can I do that in Java?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
String i = "[ hello, char[]={a,b,c} ... bye ]";

int indexOfOpenBracket = i.indexOf("[");
int indexOfLastBracket = i.lastIndexOf("]");

System.out.println(i.substring(indexOfOpenBracket+1, indexOfLastBracket));
```

**Prints:**

```
 hello, char[]={a,b,c} ... bye
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       String test = "[ abc ]";
       System.out.println(test.substring(1,test.length()-1));
       // Outputs " abc "
   }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty simple if you are sure its always enclosed in brackets

Answer (score 5):

```
String s = "[ hello, char[]={a,b,c} ... bye ]";
s = s.replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "");
```

in case of having leading and/or trailing whitespaces:

```
String s = "   [ hello, char[]={a,b,c} ... bye ] ";
s = s.trim().replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "");
```

Comment: Very Helpful, can you please explain why did you use the two escape character(/) ?

Comment: @SashiKant , java only recognize that escape mode if you put two \\ before the character

Answer (score 3):

Infact,

> this overload of substring(startIndex, endIndex);
>
> `input.substring(input.indexOf("[")+1,input.lastIndexOf("]"));`

also if you want to remove the beginning and trailing spaces, use trim();

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [String.substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method:

```
System.out.println(input.substring(1, input.length() - 1))
```

Comment: Since he seems to know the exact length of the string he can say from 1 to 23 and substring it like that.

Comment: Yes, but...in principle, one never knows how long the string is going to be.  It's always better to use what you *do* know (where the front of the string is), then let Java report the rest (where the end of the string is).

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "[ hello, char[]={a,b,c} ... bye ] ";
a.substring(1,23);
System.out.println(a);
```

There you go i miss read.

Comment: That replaces the inner brackets, which isn't what was intended.